# Can't see debug messages on node-red

Tags: node-red

I'm getting started with node-red, and I've tried the first "hello-wolrd" flow as shown bellow :

[image]

the problem that I have is, that I'm not seeing the debug message on the debug window ?  to check that it's working I've displayed the  value on the console!

Any idea what I'm missing here ?

thanks in advance !

Comment: Edit the question, include what version of node-red, browser & platform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to see messages of a debug node in the debug tab, you must assure that you have enabled it (see screenshot below).  If it is not enabled, you can enable it by clicking on it.

[image]